# Referencing a column in a parent report from a child report

Tags: reporting-services

I want to reference a column in a parent report for a report Heading in a child report - its a drill through report. The issue now is that this column is not accessible to me from the child report.

Part of my expression is:
="Year Review for " &(

But the column to reference that would dynamically change the Heading is in the parent report. Any idea how I can do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am just suggesting you. May be this is what you want.

Do one thing, just use a Switch in your sub report like,

```
=Switch(1,"Heading1",2"Heading2",3,"Heading3")
```

In your main report pass a parameter to sub report associated with heading. So your sub report will take the parameter & based on that parameter will change the heading as specified in the Switch() expression.

This is good I you have limited headings.

I would suggest try to get your headings from the database.